# How to store if user has logged in for the first time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

Drawing a blank here as I have been out of the game for some time and busy on a new application.

Objective: Send a newly registered user a welcome message with a modal when he logs in for the first time.

This should only happen the first time he logs in, for example:

##### `newuser.blade.php`

```
@if ($first_login == true)
    <h3>Welcome Popup</h3>
@else 
    <h3>Hey!  Nothing to Show</h3>
@endif
```

I have added a boolean column to my `users` table called: `first_login`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('first_login')->default(true);
    });
}
```

Made a controller called `FirstLogin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FirstLogin extends Controller
{
    public function FirstLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->first_login) {
            $first_login = true;
            Auth::user()->first_login = true;
            Auth::user()->save();
        } else {
            $first_login = false;
        }

        return view(
            'test',
            ['first_login' => $first_login]
        );
    }
}
```

What are now the next steps? I am really pulling a blank on this as, like I said, been years not building anything.

So to cut it short, the column should update after the user logs out I guess?

Because if we update the column when the user logs in the first time the modal can not be shown.

I have the feeling I am forgetting something here...

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: We would need to have a little more context. What I would do with the basic context you gave is to set a session variable to `true`, which means it is the first login. That would only happen if you automatically log the user in when it registers. If that is not the case, then I would have a column like you, set to `true` by default, so when you create a new user (registers), it will automatically be `true`. Once the user logs in, set it in a session and change it to `false`. If the user never logs out, you will never set it to `false`...

Comment: There are edge cases where the user will miss the _first login_ behavior, which is why I am asking about context or more details. Still, this sounds very opinion-based

Answer (score 0):

You can store a variable named `firstLogin` in the session when the use login for the first time.

You might use the following controller to have the sessions flag created.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->first_login) {
            $request->session()->put('firstLogin', true);
            $user->first_login = false;
            $user->save();
        }
            
        return view('test');
    }
}
```

Then in your blade template you can check if the session variable exists:

```
@if (session('firstLogin'))
    <h3>Welcome Popup</h3>
@else 
    <h3>Hey!  Nothing to Show</h3>
@endif
```

Note: This will keep showing the popup to user until a new session is established.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the `first_login` column to `logged_in_before` with default value false:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('logged_in_before')->default(false);
    });
}
```

And then, change it to true on the first opening of your dashboard:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $shouldShowWelcomeModal = false;

        if ($user->logged_in_before === false) {
            $shouldShowWelcomeModal = true;
            
            $user->logged_in_before = true;
            $user->save();
        }

        return view(
            'dashboard',
            ['show_welcome_modal' => $shouldShowWelcomeModal]
        );
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can not bind the logic to first login and just make variable `is_welcome_modal_shown` that will work as well as in the code above. Anyway, it guarantees that the modal will be shown one time and doesn't require any tricks with session and logout.